# UILocalNotification is not playing sound in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification, iphone

Hi I am using UILocalNotification in my application.

It works fine in simulator.

It gives alert and sound as well.

But when I tried installing this app on device, it shows the alert when notification comes but sound is not getting played.

Please Help.

Comment: Make sure the phone is not in silent mode!

Comment: Yes my phone is not in silent mode.Plz can u help me

Comment: The file names in device are case sensitive. Make sure you have given the sound file name in correct case

Comment: . The default value is nil (no sound). Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30 seconds, the default sound is played instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`, I am quite sure it is an iOS bug. I have tested and found that the sound does not play on iOS 4.3 but works on 4.3.1 and later.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong .caf file format, or you are not using .caf at all.

To create a .caf file, use your iTunes.

iTunes -> preferences -> Import Settings -> import using : select AIFF encoder, make custom settings if you want click OK, again OK

then select music from your library and click: advanced -> create AIFF version 
drag & drop new generated file on desktop and change extension from .aif to .caf

that's it, you have .caf file that will work on your iPhone device

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the CAF file is copied to the project's target.

You can do that by selecting the file, then in File Inspector see if Target Membership has your target selected. If it doesn't - that's your problem.